# Raising errors from multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, exception, parallel-processing

I have some code to run tasks in parallel:

```
procs = []
for task in tasks:
    procs.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(task,)))
    procs[-1].start()
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

I want to add the ability for foo() to throw a TaskFailError that I've defined. I want this error to ultimately terminate the program, so I'll reraise it in the above code, but I want to allow the other tasks to finish first. I'm not sure how to do this. I've considered something like:

```
procs = []
try:
    for task in tasks:
        procs.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(task,)))
        procs[-1].start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
except TaskFailError as err:
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    raise err
```

But repeating code is a red flag, and also what happens if a second process also raises an error?